# ¿Cómo puedo enviar valores por POST en mi formulario?

Tags: php, html

Estoy intentando enviar el valor del radiobutton y del input hidden por POST. El input hidden viene nulo, hice otra pregunta para ver ese error. Esta pregunta se centra en cómo enviar igual ambos valores por POST, pero sobre todo el radiobutton.

El código:

```
<div id="open-modal" class="modal-window">
 <div>
   <a href="#textoPropiedades" title="Close" class="modal-close">Cerrar</a>
   <h1>Complete motivo de baja</h1>
   <form method="post" action="../php/esconder_propiedad.php">
     <input type="radio" name="motivo" id="motivo" value="1"> VENDIMOS
     <input type="radio" name="motivo" id="motivo" value="2"> ARRENDAMOS
     <input type="radio" name="motivo" id="motivo" value="3"> RESERVAMOS
     <input type="radio" name="motivo" id="motivo" value="4"> NO DISPONIBLE

     <input id="id_propiedad" name="id_propiedad" type="hidden"> //Viene null, un js le da valor
     </br>
     <input class="btn btn-danger btn-xs expanded" type="submit" name="enviar" style="margin-top: 17px; width: 100px; margin-left: 108px ;" value="GUARDAR" />
   </form>
 </div>
```

En la página que recibe las variables, mi código valida primero que venga el valor del radiobutton y que su valor esté entre el 1 y el 4. Acá el código:

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST["motivo"])!=1 || $_POST["motivo"]<1 || $_POST["motivo"]>4){
   //Resto del código
}
?>
```

Al venir el valor en nulo, no entra al código. ¿En qué estaré fallando?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para la pregunta de por qué viene nulo el `<input type="hidden">` existe un respuesta sencilla: No tiene atributo `value`.

Para que un campo se envíe correctamente por **post** desde un `<form>` necesita tanto una **clave** (el `name` del campo) como un **valor** (el `value` del campo).

En tu caso necesitarías que quedase algo como:

```
<input id="id_propiedad" name="id_propiedad" type="hidden" value="mi_valor">
```

Si dices que le das valor al campo a través de una función en **JS** tendrías que añadir dicha función porque seguramente tengas ahí el problema.

Para la pregunta de los `<input type="radio">` el problema que tienes es que la condición para evaluarlos en el **PHP** no está bien planteada.

```
if(isset($_POST["motivo"])!=1 || $_POST["motivo"]<1 || $_POST["motivo"]>4){
   //Resto del código
}
```

Con esa condición lo que estás diciendo es que se meta por el `if` en caso de que `$_POST["motivo"]` sea distinto a 1 (la función `isset()` devuelve `true` o `false`, dependiendo de si la variable existe y en **PHP** `true == 1` y `false == 0)` o que sea menor que 1 o que sea mayor que 4. Con cualquiera de esas tres condiciones se cumpla te entraría por el `if`.

Ahora analicemos el problema. Imaginemos que seleccionas el `<input type="radio" name="motivo" id="motivo" value="3">`, esta se envía correctamente por **POST** y llega a la al **if** con el que tratas de evaluarla:

> **3** no es menor que **1**
>   **3** no es mayor que **4**
>   isset(3) no es distinto a **1**, de hecho es **1** porque la variable existe en `$_POST[]`.

Si lo que querías es que solamente se ejecute el código cuando `$_POST["motivo"]` exista o que su valor esté comprendido entre 1 y 4 tienes la condición completamente del revés. Deberías tener algo como;

```
//Evaluamos primero si la variable existe
if (isset($_POST["motivo"]) {
  //Evaluamos que su valor esté comprendido en 1 y 4
  if($_POST["motivo"] >= 1 && $_POST["motivo"] <= 4) {
    //Código que se ejecuta cuando el campo es correctamente validado
  }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, funcionó perfecto. =)